# Sort dataframe by rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have the following puzzle: I have a long pandas dataframe which I need to do some transformations. For simplicity, I'm showing this one

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[7,1,9], 'y':[4,5,2],'z':[1,8,3]})
```

the wanted output sould be a dataframe with all the rows sorted:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,1,2], 'b':[4,5,3],'c':[7,8,9]})
```

Is there a fast pythonic  way of doing this instead of iterating through every row and sorting them?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest because it is rowise, not columnwise

Comment: First row [7,4,1] --> [1,4,7]
Second row [1,5,8] --> [1,5,8]
Third row [9,2,3] --> [2,3,9]

Answer (score 0):

I just found it; thanks anyways

```
df_out = df.apply(lambda row: sorted(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: But that returns a Series...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [`pd.Series()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and [`df.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) to get the desired result:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x)), axis=1)
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

`df`:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  1  5  8
2  2  3  9
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose such a solution:

```py
df.transform(np.sort, axis=1)
Out[4]: 
   x  y  z
0  1  4  7
1  1  5  8
2  2  3  9
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort *each* row. Sorting *by* rows would be `df.sort_values(list(df.index), axis=1)` and would rearrange the columns, which is not what you want.

Pandas isn't really meant to change data relative to labels, so NumPy [`sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) makes more sense.

```
import numpy as np

df_out = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  1  5  8
2  2  3  9
```

Sorting is done along the last axis of the array, i.e. `1` for a df.